# How can I point vim and python-mode to custom python version

Tags: python-2.7, vim, ide, python-mode, jedi

I am trying to customize vim to work as python IDE using python-mode. But since my Redhat machine has python2.6 by default it's not picking up my custom libraries that reside in python2.7.

How can I point python-mode to suggest autocomplete from python2.7. I tried jedi and YouCompleteMe as well.

Comment: do you have gui installed? maybe installing pycharm and vim plugin instead?

Comment: No I am doing it on console only. I am, not planning to use any IDE.